# R: Select earliest date after permanent change in status (not just earliest date conditional on status, but conditional on permanent change to status)

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have data that looks like this

```
data <- data.frame(unique_id = c(rep("A",6), rep("B",6)),
               year = c(seq(2010,2015),seq(2010,2015)),
               value = c(100,100,100,0,0,0,100,0,100,100,0,0))
```

I want this:

```
output <- data.frame(unique_id = c("A","B"),
                 year = c(2013,2014))
```

What's the most efficient way to do this? I think using dplyr along the lines of `data %>% group_by(unique_id) %>% filter(value==0) %>% summarise(yr_closed = min(year))` would work, but this obviously doesn't return my desired output, and I don't know which functions to use to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `rleid`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
data %>%
   group_by(unique_id) %>% 
   slice(which.max(rleid(value))) %>%
   select(-value)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   unique_id [2]
#  unique_id  year
#  <fct>     <int>
#1 A          2013
#2 B          2014
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone referencing this question in the future, what ended up working best was adding `arrange` to @akrun's answer. I also removed `select` from the end:

```
data %>% group_by(unique_id) %>% arrange(year) %>% slice(which.max(rleid(value)))
```

This was better for my real data because I was grouping by two categories, which caused the date variable to be out of order (so the max rleid value wasn't always the latest date). Keeping `value` also helped me because my ultimate goal was to label observations with nonzero values in the latest year 'open' and label them 'closed' if their latest value was zero.